# Quote keys entered automatically when I open browser

Tags: browser, keypad

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzRRl.jpg)I ran into a problem today morning, when I opened a browser to begin my search. As i was about to start typing in search bar, I noticed that a single quote ' key is being automatically entered without me touching the keypad. I am not sure what is wrong cos this is happening across all my browsers.

Would be great if you could help me resolving this issue[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHpp2.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b1cK0.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DRu0P.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3KrFG.jpg)

Comment: Is this also happening in other apps such as Notepad? Could you also include your OS and its Version?

Comment: Yes, any textbox where I place my cursor. I am using Windows 10 and I notice this happening when I log into my system after it goes to sleep or logged out

Comment: Your key is stuck. Press it couple of times.  Maybe it will get fixed?

Comment: @Jhon Yeah thats what I said in the answer below.

Comment: @Gantendo Oh I didn't looked there. Well OK

Comment: Thanks guys, That is how I have been trying to stop it. It didn't stop there, I now see keys such as comma , uppercase letters H, lower case letter u. Attached new picture above in my question

Answer (score 0):

The key is probably stuck. You can press it a couple times to make it unstuck. Maybe wiggle it a bit. You can even remove the keycap (carefully!) and look at what's below.